# Saving bootstrap time picker value in PHP and MYsql

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap timepicker to select the shift start time and shift end time.I am posting the start time and end time values to a another php script to store it in Database. I used strtotime function to convert the timepicker values and then store it in database but no luck.
Both the times in the database value are stored as same value even after converting.

```
$converted_starttime = strtotime($_POST['starttime']);
$converted_endtime = strtotime($_POST['endtime']);
```

I also want to do the comparisons using this shift start time and shift end time. Is there any better way to store the timepicker values into the database so that it can be easily used for comparisons. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what is a type of db field ?

Comment: I am using TIME datatype

Comment: try to print $converted_starttime = strtotime($_POST['starttime']); value and put db manually ...

Comment: If I select the time as 6:00 AM in the start time picker then the converted value using strtotime is 1401301800 but if checked in DB the  value is 838:59:59. Which datatype to be used in the DB to store the converted value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution :

change the database type in integer you can not save **int** in **time** type field

**[SEE THIS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-types.html)**

Answer (score 0):

strtotime converts the value to a linux timestamp which is a number. If you must save as a datetime in the database then you need to pass the correct datetime format.

Something like:

`$datetime=date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($_POST['starttime']);`

make sure to use correct separator.